# Unit tests crashing in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, gcov

[image]When unit tests are run in Xcode 7 (both GM and 7.0.1), the tests pass; but immediately after that, it crashes.

Xcode debug console shows the following error:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument

The logs also show a lot of these errors:

---

Test Suite 'MyTests' passed at 2015-10-05 09:20:54.028.
     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.002) seconds

Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2015-10-05 09:20:54.028.
     **Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.001 (0.003) seconds**

profiling: /Users/ldupont/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayerIOS-dpnbmmngypdkcsbguaesyimldsvi/Build/Intermediates/PlayerIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PlayerIOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/**SCPlayerTabularCollectionView.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory**

profiling: /Users/ldupont/Documents/Fuego/Player_ios/PlayerIOS/ObjectiveC.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory

profiling: /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayerIOS-dpnbmmngypdkcsbguaesyimldsvi/Build/Intermediates/PlayerIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PlayerIOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCPlayerTabularCollectionView.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory

profiling: /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayerIOS-dpnbmmngypdkcsbguaesyimldsvi/Build/Intermediates/PlayerIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PlayerIOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SCPlayerTabularCollectionView.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory

profiling: /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayerIOS-dpnbmmngypdkcsbguaesyimldsvi/Build/Intermediates/PlayerIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PlayerIOS.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/**SCPlayerTabularCollectionView.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory**

profiling: /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlayerIOS-dpnbmmngypdkcsbguaesyimldsvi/Build/Intermediates/PlayerIOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/

---

My project settings are as follows:
Main target and test target: 
   Enable Code Coverage Support: YES
   Generate Legacy Test Coverage Files: NO
   Instrument Program Flow: NO

I tried setting all the above to NO as well, but that didn't help.

Comment: What exactly is SCPlayerTabularCollectionView? Is it in a third-party framework / library? It sounds like this isn't configured for compatibility with testing.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. The library that we were using was compiled with the Instrumentation project setting to YES. After integrating a new version with that setting set to NO, the unit tests worked fine.

Comment: Well done. Glad you got it solved. You should answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can accept your answer). This might be useful to others who use this library!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found what was causing the crash - the internal library that I was using was compiled with the project setting '**Instrument Program Flow**'= **YES**, in order to generate gcov-based code coverage. This is no longer supported in Xcode 7 which dropped legacy gcov file format support in favor of new intermediate format — profdata.

I obtained a new version of that library with the Instrument setting set to **NO** and then the crash disappeared and all unit tests passed. Hope this helps someone else who is facing the same issue.

Comment: you are a savior... I needed to set this on my unit test bundle to keep the device from crashing in a weird state.